# Draggable object - dragging from title

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

I have this HTML popup object 
[image]
I made it draggable with jQuery. Now I can drag this popup from any point in the object, which causes problems with the scrolling - if I try to scroll by dragging the little rectangle inside the scrollbar - it drags the whole popup.

I want to make it possible to drag the popup only by dragging the title - so if I drag the title it will drag the whole popup, but I won't be able to drag the popup from any other point (the textarea, the white background, the scrollbar....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `handles` in Jquery UI

> If specified, restricts dragging from starting unless the mousedown
>   occurs on the specified element(s). Only elements that descend from
>   the draggable element are permitted.

Eg:

```
$( "your popup" ).draggable({
  handle: "title id"
});
```

Refer [handle](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle)